cloud-init and additional ipv6 addresses?
what is the intended, reliable, and clean way to add additional ipv6 addresses to a virtual system running Ubuntu server configured by cloud-init (e.g. cloud provider, LXD,...)?

typically, cloud-init creates /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml, and it would be easy to just add the additional addresses to the file, but afaik cloud-init overwrites this file whenever the provider changes settings, e.g. the DNS resolvers. Changes would be lost then, arent't they?
on the other hand, netplan seems to accept only one file per network device, so it isn't clear whether it is correct to add a second file. When I tried it with a second file, it worked, but this contradicts the netplan man page, which says "Lexicographically later files (regardless of in which directory they are) amend (new mapping keys) or override (same mapping keys)  previous ones." , so adding a second file should – following the man page – override, and thus wipe out the address configuration in 50-cloud-init.yaml

So even if putting in a second file seems to work at the moment, will this reliably work in future, or vanish with some netplan update?
regards
